# /Date(1341788400000+0100)/ to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM

Tags: php, datetime, date, time, format

I have several dates being outputted into variables. They are formatted as follows:

```
/Date(1341788400000+0100)/
```

How would I go about formatting them using PHP into:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you've found a solution, why not answer your own question?

Comment: It wouldn't let me at the time because I was a new user. Will update now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the following, as the initial format was in milliseconds:

```
$date = 1341788400000+0100;
$date = ( $date / 1000 );
$date = date("d/m/Y H:m", $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = 1341788400000+0100;
echo date("Y/m/d H:m",$date);
```

Unless the +0100 is the actual time of the day (01:00) ?

Comment: +0100 normally suggests offset from GMT

Comment: I would have assumed that the +0100 was the timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

First, you parse it, e.g. using `strtok()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php

Then parse it as a number.

```
$seconds = intval($a)
```

Then format it using

```
date("Y/m/d H:m", $seconds)`.
```