# Convert Numeric Value to DateTime

Tags: r

I have the below numeric value. I need to convert it into datetime format.

```
1627074000000
```

To see more values like this (for e.g. 1627077600000), you can refer the link below -
https://coindatadesktop.com/coins/getRelatives.php?symbol=VNDC&limit=48&modo=pre

I googled a bit and found ([here](http://www.espn.com/espn3/feeds/upcoming)) it's in GMT format.

```
<startTimeGmtMs>1627243200000</startTimeGmtMs>
<endTimeGmtMs>1627248600000</endTimeGmtMs>
```

I tried this but returns invalid date -

```
as.POSIXct(1627243200000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be in `miliseconds`:

try:

```
as.POSIXct(1627243200000/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
[1] "2021-07-25 20:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: Beat me by 28s, upvote.

Comment: Duplicate though, answered same/similar question years ago (at least once).  Booh: wasn't an accepted answer hence not eligible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921425/143305.  Found another eligible one (and of course upvoted this answer which is still correct, if only redundant given the dupes).